# After moving to Homestead server laravel cant find view files

Tags: laravel

I recently switched from Mac local apache, mysql setup to Vagrant Laravel/Homestead server. When trying to run my app. it gives me the following error.

```
View [components.people.feed] not found.
```

My Feed Method:

```
return view('components.people.feed')->with('people', $people);
```

My View Directory

```
resources
-
 views
  -
   components
    -
     people
      -
      feed.blade.php
```

My app works on our production server here at work. it returns no errors. 
only when run on Homestead server.

Could it be a homestead problem? first time trying to work with it.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: routes file. http://laravel.io/bin/XyqBB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help, but sounds like it's also a cache-related problem. So, try this:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Ok, it's also just a guess, but did you modify `/config/view.php` when you developed a project? It shoud have `'paths' => [realpath(base_path('resources/views')), ],`

Comment: no i havnt modified that file. the contents are the same: 'paths' => [realpath(base_path('resources/views')), ],

Comment: i gave that a try. no luck (

Comment: Ok. Run `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan optimize --force`. Also, try to connect to VM and look there with ls command if Homestead sees your view: `vagrant ssh` and `ls project/rosources/views/components/people`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110628/discussion-between-wes-murray-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was an issue with case sensitive file paths/filenames to the view files.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing cache on the production server solved my problem:

```
//Clear Cache facade value:
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return '<h1>Cache facade value cleared</h1>';
});

//Route cache:
Route::get('/route-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:cache');
    return '<h1>Routes cached</h1>';
});

//Clear Route cache:
Route::get('/route-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
    return '<h1>Route cache cleared</h1>';
});

//Clear View cache:
Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    return '<h1>View cache cleared</h1>';
});

//Clear Config cache:
Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return '<h1>Clear Config cleared</h1>';
});
```